# Threshold is exceeded (>5000 elements) but View still working. Why?

Tags: 2016, list-view-threshold

I have a list of the normal Threshold of 5000 elements. This Threshold is exceeded (currently we have round about 5500 elements in this list).

**However, it is possible to view all elements in the view. Normally it should display a message (This view cannot be displayed because it exceeded the threshold ...).**

So my question: How is this possible?
What I checked so far:

- The filter in the view of the list (no filter activated)
- Are there really 5000+ elements (exported via excel / extended item limit to 5000: there are two pages)
- Custom WebParts in the page with some custom code (no, it is a standard list view)
- List view in some unknown way custom edited (Created a new list view with the same result)
- What is the normal list behavior (Checked on another list the threshold behavior: like expected, the threshold message is displayed)
- Checked via PowerShell list property EnableThrottling (it's true)

I'm site collection admin, the list has no custom permissions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a site collection administrator, the threshold is 20 000 items. If you ask someone that is not an SCA, they will hit the threshold.

A normal user will hit the threshold limit.

> **List view threshold - greater than 5,000 - Threshold**
>
> Specifies the maximum number of list or library items that a database
>   operation, such as a query, can process at the same time outside the
>   daily time window set by the administrator during which queries are
>   unrestricted.  When adding or removing a column index, the threshold
>   is 20,000 by default.  When deleting a list or folder, the threshold
>   is 100,000 by default.  When renaming a folder within the same
>   library, the threshold is 100,000 by default.
>
> **List view threshold for auditors and administrators - 20,000 -
>   Threshold**
>
> Specifies the maximum number of list or library items that a database
>   operation, such as a query, can process at the same time when they are
>   performed by an auditor or administrator with appropriate permissions.
>   This setting works with Allow Object Model Override.

[Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0#list-and-library-limits)

**Update**

SharePoint 2016 is a little bit smarter when it comes down to list and libraries performance and creates indexed columns on it's own where needed to improve the overall performance. At 2500 items, SharePoint starts to index columns by itself.

Compare the two lists by going to advanced settings and just below all the columns there should be a link called "Indexed Columns".

[SharePoint 2016: List View Threshold](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34086.sharepoint-2016-list-view-threshold.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but again: I have in the same site two lists with more than 5000+ elements. One list I can view without any problem and the another one with the expected threshold message

Comment: @Oskar, SharePoint 2016 as a little bit smarter when it comes down to performance and creates it's own indexed columns when needed to improve the performance. Compare the two lists by going to advanced settings and just below all the columns there should be a link called "Indexed Columns". Any difference there between the two lists?

Comment: You're right, I forgot to check the indexed columns there. I know that SharePoint 2016 is in this point a little bit smarter and generates automatically indexed columns. And I think this is the hint I needed: We migrated some weeks ago from SP2013 to SP2016 and had in the other list already custom indexed columns - that's the list where the threshold message is displayed. The list without the message and more than 5000+ elements exceeded this limit after we migrated and don't had any indexed columns. Now it has an automatic generated indexed column and it works without the message ;-)

Comment: If you add this as answer I can mark it :-)

Answer (score 4):

The view on a list is just a query to the Content Database in the back end which stores the data for the list.  A SharePoint list can hold millions of items in them. You need to index your list data to help with the threshold limit.  List item threshold is a query limit, and not a list limit.  Your view will still work, but there is a chance it will timeout if it continues to be queried and you do not do something about the large query.

It will not hurt performance too much to up the threshold limit to 10000 in Central Admin if needed.  Make sure to update your default view and your view all items view to index your columns if you are going to pull more than 5000 items in you view query.  [Here is a link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0) that explains indexing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how the index is working and I know the query limits on the view. I already explained in my post that I checked a comparable list and the behaviour is like expected: threshold message is displayed.