# was the sharepoint list threshold increased on SP online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view-threshold

after doing some testings we found out that our list views surpassing the item limit threshold were still working even when the item limit was greater than 5,000 and it would keep working unless the item limit per page was greater than 5,000 items

in the past, no matter your page limit, if the list returned more than 5,000 results it would error out with the threshold message.

was this recently changed  ?

Comment: check [this](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/8463457-remove-the-list-view-threshold-5000-by-default) link. Looks like they have made some improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List View Threshold changed from a maximum 5000 items per view to greater than 5000 items. Yes, you are reading it correctly, Now it is more than 5000 items in a view but what is an upper limit? Sorry, we don't know.

Upper Limit: It depends on the SQL hardware, SharePoint server's hardware, and structure of site collections.

Now they introduced new values for the following.

- List View Threshold: Greater than 5000. Specifies the maximum number of list or library items that a database operation, such as a query, can process at the same time outside the daily time window set by the administrator during which queries are unrestricted.
- When adding or removing a column index, the threshold is 20,000 by
  default.
- When deleting a list or folder, the threshold is 100,000 by
  default.
- When renaming a folder within the same library, the
  threshold is 100,000 by default.
- List view threshold for auditors and
  administrators will remain same at 20,000.
- List view lookup
  threshold: 12 join operations per query

[Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34086.sharepoint-2016-list-view-threshold.aspx) is for SharePoint 2016 OnPremises, but this also applies to SharePoint Online.

Another thing is a different threshold between SiteCollection Admins and normal users:

> **List View Threshold - 5,000**
> Specifies the maximum number of list or library items that a database operation, such as a query, can process at one time. Operations that exceed this limit are blocked.
>
> To give you time to make alternative plans, you may be warned on the List Settings page when your list has exceeded 3,000 items. The warning contains a help link to this topic.
>
> **List View Threshold size for auditors and administrators - 20,000**
>
> Specifies the maximum number of list or library items that a database operation, such as a query, can process at one time when performed by an auditor or administrator with appropriate permissions. This setting works in conjunction with Allow Object Model Override.

[Threshold is exceeded (>5000 elements) but View still working. Why?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239640/threshold-is-exceeded-5000-elements-but-view-still-working-why)

[Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 1):

No, the list threshold is applied to all version of SharePoint including SP Online. Currently, increasing the List View Threshold in SharePoint Online is not permitted.

The List View Threshold is by default, approximately 5000 items. This means the list threshold is a approximate figure. If you add index column and filter with list view, then the list view item count won't exceed the threshold limitation(Maybe you have added index column or filter with your view).

[image]

Reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: for site collection administrators the Threshold has been increased... but as the previous answer said the limit is unknown and unofficial